# progress bar around another control

Tags: android

I have a **TextView** with oval shaped semi-transparent background:

[image]

I need to show a progress bar running around this oval background.

Here is my TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background" />
```

custom_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#80000000" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="70dp"
        android:topRightRadius="70dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="70dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="70dp"
        />

    <padding
        android:bottom=20dp"
        android:left="40dp"
        android:right="40dp"
        android:top="20dp" />

</shape>
```

Any help will be really appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean that you need a line to draw around the edge of the oval, starting at some point and eventually coming all the way back around to that point when the progress is 100? Or just you want a circular progress bar surrounding the text/oval?

Comment: Yes, I need a line to draw around the edge of the oval. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: You want an oval shape so instead of drawing a circle as in the following guides, use an oval. Try [this](https://mattj.io/circularseekbar/) or [this](https://github.com/JesusM/HoloCircleSeekBar).

Answer (score 0):

As you want to have a custom shaped progress bar which can match your shape drawable, [FABProgressCircle](https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/FABProgressCircle) is the thing you should use.

[FABProgressCircle](https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/FABProgressCircle) library works upon any fab/image/shape drawable and all the documentation is already given on the following link.

What you can do is just add this code to your xml after importing the library.

```
<com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle
    android:id="@+id/fabProgressCircle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">       
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_background"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>    
</com.github.jorgecastilloprz.FABProgressCircle>
```

Try this out.